# Inserting additional code into the onclick attribute of a submit button using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, button, onclick, form-submit

I'm having trouble trying to properly insert additional code into the onclick attribute of a submit button.  I don't want to overwrite anything within the onclick but just add additional code.   I have successfully inserted the code needed but when I look at the source code of the button it shows some additional functionality that shouldn't be there so i don't think I have it written out properly.

**Here's the button:**

```
<input id='TESTFrmSubmit' type='submit' value='Submit' name='submitButton' onclick='formSubmit(document.getElementById("TESTForm_1001")); return false;' />
```

**The additional code I want to insert into the onclick attribute is:**

```
'_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Whitepaper Campaign', 'Submit Button','conceptshareexample.pdf'']);'
```

**The jquery I have that inserts the additonal code into the onclick attribute is:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#TESTFrmSubmit").attr ("onclick", function() { 

return this.onclick + "'_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Whitepaper Campaign', 'Submit Button','TESTexample.pdf'']);'";

  });

  });
```

The problem I'm having is that when i view the source code of the button, it contains 
**function onclick(event)** within the onclick displaying it like so:

```
onclick="function onclick(event){ formSubmit(document.getElementById("TESTForm_1010")); return false; }_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Whitepaper Campaign', 'Submit Button','TESTexample.pdf'']);"
```

I need it to display it like this without the **function onclick(event)**:

```
onclick="{formSubmit(document.getElementById("TESTForm_1010")); return false; }_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Whitepaper Campaign', 'Submit Button','TESTexample.pdf'']);"
```

Please help!  this has been racking my brain...

Comment: What a mess of a question...Code formatting?

Comment: Please re-edit the question, insert Codes formatted (select and press the 'Code Sample' button), so we can help better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `.attr('onclick'`, you can bind into the event handler directly:

```
$('#mktFrmSubmit').click(function ()
{
    doSomething();
    alert('hi');
}
$('#mktFrmSubmit').click(function ()
{
    alert('We can also bind to .click multiple times, and it adds events');
    // Instead of just overwriting them
}
```

Now clicking `#mktFrmSubmit` will fire both those click handlers.

Comment: thanks!  i thinking this should work! thanks again for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.onclick
```

is returning the

```
function onclick(event) {...
```

To accomplish what you want, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#mktFrmSubmit").attr ("onclick", function() {

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Whitepaper Campaign', 'Submit Button','conceptshareexample.pdf']);
formSubmit(document.getElementById("TESTForm_1001")); return false;

});

});
```